# Подключение USB-устройств в VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Возникла необходимость развернуть виртуальную машину. Процесс разворачивания прошел вроде без ошибок: загрузился с ISO, развернул образ, всё работает.

На следующий день возвращаюсь к данной виртуальной машине, подготавливаю к переносу на реальное железо (другой компьютер), и тут меня ждет разочарование: не могу подключить USB-устройство, чтобы сделать на него бэкап образа.

В настройках виртуальной машины на вкладке USB невозможно добавить USB-устройство (VirtualBox не видит физические устройства).

Пробовал удалять и ставить всё заново - не помогло. Как решить такую проблему?

**P.S.:** Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ был найден [здесь](http://blog.dvteam.ru/?p=320).

Для того чтобы ответ сохранился здесь, приведу цитату из текста:

> Причина того, что виртуальная машина не может работать с подключенными
>   устройствами — установленный USB Filter. Не какой то конкретный,
>   варианты могут быть разные. Это может быть AMD USB Filter, который
>   установлен вместе с Catalyst Control Centre или фильтр, который
>   устанавливается Sony Ericsson PC Suite или какой то другой фильтр.
>
> Для отключения фильтра придется править реестр. Запускаем regedit с
>   правами администратора и открываем вот эту ветку:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}
>
> В ней ищем ключ с именем UpperFilter и удаляем его или просто
>   переименовываем чтобы система не использовала его значение

Мне данное решение очень помогло.

Answer (score -1):

Если из под Linux, то вполне возможно, что вашей учетной записи нет в группе vboxusers.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?